# shell interprets quotes as string

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell script, so one of the first things to learn is something like:

```
echo "Hello there"
```

However, this returns:

```
"Hello there"
```

The shell seems to interpret quotes as part of the string.
This is not limited to the echo command, but also, for example: printf or read.

Comment: Which shell, which operating system are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this if I copy paste the `echo "Hello there"` into a bash shell. Can you tell us more about your environment and what you are actually doing/typing (e.g. copy paste a terminal session you perform so we can see what you type and what the output is)

Comment: Well I tested it on my Macbook pro with Sierra and it seemed to work fine. But I'm trying to make the transition to linux, so for this question I'm on an ubuntu 17.04. My bash is version 4.4.7.

Comment: Your observed output should not happen in *any* POSIX shell, let alone `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not equivalent: `¨` and `"`. In the shell, use `"` (34, \x22) for double quotes, not `“` or `”` etc.

Comment: Well now i feel kind of stupid, but you made my day!